# How exactly does the response "infintely many" answer the question of "how many"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, problem-solving

I admit that the level of this question is roughly about middle school, but this is what the question asks:

> The ratio of nickels to dimes to quarters is 3:8:1. If all the coins were dimes, the amount of money would be the same. Show that there are infinitely many solutions to this problem.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Do you not understand how there could be infinitely many solution to a problem?

Comment: If anybody presents a list with $n$ (ten, a million, a gazillion) solutions, it is always possible to find another solution not on the list.

Comment: I think the plan is to start with only one quarter coin, eight dimes and three nickles and check that the numbers add up. Can you then give a solution which involves two quarters? Three quarters? Four quarters? $n$ quarters? How many solutions are there?

Comment: Why do you think "infinitely many" *doesn't* answer the question?

Comment: Incidentally, "infinity" is a noun, and quite different from the adjective "infinite" or the adverb "infinitely". In many contexts, the answer to "how many" or other questions -- even if the answer is *infinite* -- is simply not an object that goes by the name "infinity".

Comment: I fear I am putting words in your mouth since you haven't offered your own thoughts... but it's not terribly unreasonable to think that there should be a *quantitative* answer, much like how we can answer "zero" rather than "there aren't any". The usual answers are $\aleph_0$ or $\omega$, depending on whether you are referring to the concept of cardinal or ordinal numbers, although it is not unreasonable to mean the question in a way that $\infty$ (meaning the extended natural number, which is the same as the extended real number called $\infty$) is the correct quantative answer.

Comment: So, is the question about explaining infinity on a middle-school level?

Comment: The question in your title is fairly different from the one in your post. To answer "How exactly does the response “infintely many” answer the question of “how many”?", I would say: In some contexts, poorly. Different infinite sets may have different sizes (cardinalities), and simply saying "infinitely many" does not tell us which of the many options we have in front of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $n,d,q$ be the quantity of nickels, dimes and quarters respectively.

The fact they are in ratio 3:8:1 means for every 12 coins:  3 are nickels , 8 are dimes and 1 is a quarter.

So if we have 12 coins exactly there are 3 nickels, 8 dimes and 1 quarter (1.20 dollars total). On the other hand if we had 12 dimes it would be the same.

So the case with 12 works. What about the case with 24? Well we would just end up having twice of each coin and the cash would add up to 2.40 dollars. And 24 dimes also give 2.40 dollars.

We can use this method for any multiple of 12. And there are infinite of those.

Hope this helps, Regards.

Comment: of course, but generally math questions aren't about the real world

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 statements here

1. The ratio of nickels to dimes to quarters is 3:8:1.

   If all the coins were dimes, the amount of money would be the same.

Believe it or not (do the math and you'll see), the second statement is another way of saying that there are 3 times as many nickels as there are quarters. But we already have that information in the first statement. So you could restate the problem as follows

> The ratio of nickels to dimes to quarters is 3:8:1. Show that there are infinitely many solutions to this problem.

for any $q\in\mathbb{N^+}, (n,d,q)=(3q,8q,q)$ is a solution.
Where $\mathbb{N^+}$={1,2,3,4,...}. Because $\mathbb{N^+}$ has an infinite number of elements, there are an infinite number of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Three nickels and a quarter make up $40$ cents, as do four dimes. As a consequence, the second sentence in your problem does not amount to an additional condition. It follows that any multiple of the package "$3$ nickels, $8$ dimes, and $1$ quarter" solves the problem.